# I like English language

Tags: articles, definite-article

> **English is a language**
>
> **The English are fine people**.
>
> **I like English language.**

I know that we say the English language.

My question is:

**I want the red book**

There may be many red books  and I want a particular red book.

is it ungrammatical  to say *English language*  since we  are referring to only one language-English?

Comment: Not all grammatical sentences make sense. "I want **the** red book" makes sense only in a context where there is no ambiguity. As you note, there are many red books in the world. But a previous sentence (not shown) may make it clear which red book is the one talked about. That goes to show that it's hard to define exactly if a sentence is grammatical in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  You should say "I like the English language."  Here, English is an adjective.  There are many languages, and the one you like is the English language.

Or, you can say "I like English." (not "the English")  In this case, English is a proper noun and does not take an article.

Comment: @pfsalad.I like  the English  means  I like   English people.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.  If you’re talking about the language, leave out “the”.